# Change Route Config and Resource file on the basis of Language Selection in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, globalization

I want to change Resource File and RouteConfig File on the basis of language selection. Currently, my application working for Single Language but now I want to convert it into multi-language.

On Startup.cs i am registering my Resource and Route Config file

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
         
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");
        CustomRequestCulture.Register(app, Configuration);
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        LocaleBasedRouting.Register(app,Configuration);
      
    }
```

In CustomRequestCultureClass, setting the culture and in LocaleBasedouting Class,Setting the Route File Like this:

```
public class LocaleBasedRouting
{
    public static void Register(IApplicationBuilder app, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
       
        switch (configuration["Locale"])
        {
            case "hi-IN":
                 app.UseMvc(c =>RouteConfigHi.Use(c));
            break;
            case "as-IN":
                  app.UseMvc(c =>RouteConfigAs.Use(c));
            break;

            default:
               app.UseMvc(c =>            
         RouteConfigEn.Use(c)
        );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a dropdown to change the language, On Language Selection able to change the Culture language but Don't know how to change Route File as well?

On `OnActionExecuting` i am updating the Culture Info.I tried to call `LocaleBasedRouting.Register` function from  `OnActionExecuting` function but because of `IApplicationBuilder` i am facing an issue.Dependency Injection also not working for `IApplicationBuilder`

Comment: You should not change your routes based on translation. The routes of your software aka (the url which will be called) should be agnostic from the language. Translation should be only used in the UI level.

Comment: What is your `RouteConfigHi` and `RouteConfigEn` and `RouteConfigAs`?